# Latex ignores natbib longnamesfirst option when using "econometrica" bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am confounded as to why in this document latex is ignoring the natbib longnamesfirst option. I have used it in other documents without any problem. Any ideas are appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[longnamesfirst,authoryear]{natbib}



\begin{document}

I want to cite \citet{BGG:1999} with the full list of authors names and then I want this citation \citet{BGG:1999} to appear with only the first author's names followed by et al. (1999).

\bibliographystyle{econometrica}
\bibliography{test_bib}

\end{document}
```

Here is the example bib file:

```
%%test_bib
@InCollection{BGG:1999,
author={Bernanke, Ben S. and Gertler, Mark and Gilchrist, Simon},
editor={J. B. Taylor and M. Woodford},
title={The financial accelerator in a quantitative business cycle framework},
booktitle={Handbook of Macroeconomics},
publisher={Elsevier},
year=1999,
month={},
volume={1},
number={},
series={Handbook of Macroeconomics},
edition={},
chapter={21},
pages={1341-1393}
}
```

And here is the output I am getting:

[image: Output from test.tex]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Where is `econometrica` coming from? Please notice that a bibstyle has to be prepared in a special way to be compatible with `natbib`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `econometrica.bst` in CTAN is in the “obsolete” tree. It doesn't cooperate with `natbib` to allow `longnamesfirst` to act.

The successor seems to be `ecta` and, indeed, the following input seems to produce the correct output (but with a small difference in the placement of the publisher).

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@InCollection{BGG:1999,
  author={Bernanke, Ben S. and Gertler, Mark and Gilchrist, Simon},
  editor={J. B. Taylor and M. Woodford},
  title={The financial accelerator in a quantitative business cycle framework},
  booktitle={Handbook of Macroeconomics},
  publisher={Elsevier},
  year=1999,
  month={},
  volume={1},
  number={},
  series={Handbook of Macroeconomics},
  edition={},
  chapter={21},
  pages={1341-1393},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[longnamesfirst,authoryear]{natbib}

\begin{document}

I want to cite \citet{BGG:1999} with the full list of authors names and then I want this citation
\citet{BGG:1999} to appear with only the first author's names followed by et al. (1999).

\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is just to make the environment selfcontained.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, using the long or short version of the citation requires the cooperation of the bibliography style, `econometrica` in your case. It might be that it does not support abbreviated names, or that other measures are necessary. Anyway the behaviour you are after is style-dependent, as [this](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=5947) and [this](https://quote.ucsd.edu/rogblog/2010/09/21/getting-the-longnamesfirst-option-to-work-with-natbib-in-latex/) post imply.